# Base Support for a Tree house

Tags: structural-engineering, design, stresses, beam, concrete

I am building a tree house in my backyard and it is going to be relatively simple. There are no parts that require drilling into the tree. The whole house is propped up by four 4x4 wood supports. I'm wondering if quikrete is the way to best support the whole structure or if there are better alternatives.

Comment: The DIY Stack...

Comment: I saw a promo video of someone using a two-part expanding (urethane?) foam for holding up posts - seemed quick and easy, in the video at least!

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of building a tree house if the house is not actually connected to the tree?

Anyway, yes concrete foundations should work. There are two points that I would suggest considering though:

- The wood should not be in direct contact with the concrete or the ground. Use some kind of steel brackets and ensure that water can drain from the joint. A post bracket could be used. For example this [rebar bracket](https://www.strongtie.com/nonstandoffpostbases_postbases/rcps_saddle/p/rcps).
- Make sure to dig deep enough when pouring the concrete. You are going to put in a long lever and probably want to make sure that your house does not move when you bump against it.

Comment: The tree goes through the house, but doesn't carry any more weight than itself. So by saying the wood shouldn't make contact with the concrete, no matter if it's pressure treated, you mean I should put some metal around the wood that would be underground/surrounded by concrete.

Comment: Yes, even pressure treated wood should not be in direct contact with concrete.  Moisture in the concrete and from rain will otherwise lead to rot. It added a link to a post bracket that could be used for mounting your posts. Anything similar to that would probably do.